# How to make one of two fields required in Nestjs DTO with its proper API documentation?

Tags: nestjs, dto, class-validator, nestjs-swagger

For example:

```
{
  phone: string 
  email: string
  ....
  ....
  otherFields
  ....
  ....
}
```

Either **phone** or **email** should be **required** in request body. I found solution only for validation, here is:

```
export class MyDto {
   @IsString()
   @ValidateIf((obj, value) => !obj.email || value)
   phone: string;

   @IsString()
   @ValidateIf((obj, value) => !obj.phone || value)
   phone: string;

   ..... other fields .....
  }
```

However, how to apply swagger documentation for this?
There are oneOf and anyOf in OAS3 docs. Here is suitable solution in terms of swagger:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72218716/how-to-define-in-swagger-spec-either-of-two-properties-are-not-null-and-required)

How is it possible to implement **both** validation and swagger docs at the same time?

Answer (score 3):

The only alternative that I see for your problem is this.

```js
export class EmailDto {
  @ApiProperty()
  @IsString()
  email: string;
}

export class PhoneDto {
  @ApiProperty()
  @IsString()
  phone: string;
}

export class CreateCatDto {
  @ApiProperty({
    oneOf: [
      {
        type: 'object',
        required: ['phoneNumber'],
        properties: {
          phoneNumber: { type: 'string' },
        },
      },
      {
        type: 'object',
        required: ['email'],
        properties: { email: { type: 'string' } },
      },
    ],
  })
  @ValidateNested()
  @Type((type) => (type.object.phoneOrEmail.email ? EmailDto : PhoneDto))
  phoneOrEmail: PhoneDto | EmailDto;
}
```

Here you have the documentation for [anyOf](https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/types-and-parameters#oneof-anyof-allof) in NestJs
I didn't use `getSchemaPath` because my schema wasn't initialised by Swagger so I create manually my schema in `@ApiProperty`

And for the `class-validator` I ask to validate the DTO for the right Type with `@ValidateNested()` and `@Type()`.

The problem is. If they sent you both email and phoneNumber `class-validator` will only validate email because:

`(type.object.phoneOrEmail.email ? EmailDto : PhoneDto)`

If there is an email, it will validate the class EmailDto first. So you need to tell if there are Email and PhoneNumber you need to validate a DTO with both.

Go check on Google if there is an anyOf like for `class-validaor`